# When using perf, how can I only focus on the parts I care about?

Tags: performance, rust, perf

I have a program that can roughly be divided into four parts: `data reading`, `data transformation`, `computation`, and `data writing`, like this

```rust
fn main(){
  let raw_data = read_from_file();
  let data = transform(raw_data);
  let result = compute(data);
  write_back(result);
}
```

I only care about the computation part. The `computation part` may only take five seconds, while the other parts take several minutes.

It may be a good idea to profile specifically for `computation`, but I want to observe the program's performance on real datasets.

In addition to the execution of functions, I also want to obtain information such as cache hit rate.

What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [perf stat for part of program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26267588) .  Or use `perf_event_open` manually, but fork+exec and later kill of `perf stat -p ...` is pretty effective if the phases take long enough (multiple seconds)  Oh, and [Enable/disable perf event collection programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70314376) discusses how there's a control FD where you can control it by writing to a pipe.