# Perf record after my code reaches a certain point?

Tags: x86-64, perf, micro-optimization

My code uses multiple threads to parse json, becomes single threaded, merges them into a tree then processes it. When I do perf record it says 70% of my code is in the JSON part and building the tree. All other code is 1.1 or 0.9% and I can't tell what's slow. However if I do an early return I find the 70% of my code is actually 40% of my wall clock.

I was wondering if there's a way my code can signal to perf when to start recording? I can't tell the branch misses of the second half of the code easily when the json part is the majority of it. It's also harder to figure out where my cache misses are when multiple threads are saying the json code miss a lot.

Alternatively, if it's recorded in a graph, if there's a way to say ignore everything outside of this part of the graph (the function that contains the second half of my code) it'd be much easier to narrow down problematic areas

Comment: One trick is to have your process fork/exec `perf` with your PID as a command line arg.  But yeah it should be possible to filter perf samples, maybe by time, and probably excluding certain functions if you want.  I'm not an expert in that, though.

Comment: [perf stat for part of program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26267588) for `perf stat`, would also work with `perf record`.  [How to start and stop perf sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46938544) for filtering `perf record`.  Also [Enable/disable perf event collection programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70314376) for a more modern way for the process being profiled to enable/disable collection by writing messages on a control pipe.

Comment: Great ty @PeterCordes! Do you happen to know what the heck `exec {ctl_fd}<>${ctl_fifo}` is suppose to mean? It's written as that in the man page too. Shouldn't this be ${ctl_fd}? TBH I'm not sure what those both should be either. I'm sure I can figure this out when I need it

Comment: In a shell script, `exec` without a command performs the redirections for the shell itself.  `number<>path` redirects that file-descriptor to a read/write open of that file.  Like `open`/`dup2`.  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Opening-File-Descriptors-for-Reading-and-Writing .  So yes, it should be `${ctl_fd}` to expand that shell variable, whose value is a number.  Updated Hadi's answer on the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perf allows you to use control file descriptors to enable or disable counting. It is documented under [`perf stat`'s man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html#:%7E:text=3%20%2D%2Dappend%20%E2%80%94%20%24cmd-,%2D%2Dcontrol%3Dfifo%3Actl,-%2Dfifo%5B%2Cack%2Dfifo), but it also works for `perf record`.

In short:

- You need to have a file descriptor ready and pass it to both `perf stat` or `perf record` (with `--control fd:${ctl_fd}`) and your application (`argv`, environment variables, or however else your want). When your application decides to have perf start measuring, it sends `enable\n` to that file descriptor and `disable\n` to stop.
- Optionally, if you want perf to acknowledge that it did what you asked, you need to have a second file descriptor ready and pass both to perf with `--control fd:${ctl_fd},${ctl_fd_ack}`. Perf will respond by writing 5 bytes back (i.e., `ack\n` followed by a null-terminator) that your application can read and check.

If the example in the documentation looks cryptic or too terse for you, here is an expanded version (NOTE: this code is intended to be short, it is NOT safe or suitable for production):

```c
#include <assert.h>    // assert
#include <stddef.h>    // size_t
#include <stdio.h>     // printf
#include <stdlib.h>    // atoi, getenv
#include <string.h>    // strcmp
#include <unistd.h>    // read, write

size_t fib(size_t n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int perf_ctl_fd;
    int perf_ctl_ack_fd;
    char ack[5];
    size_t n;
    size_t r;

    // // Make sure we have the right number of arguments
    // if (argc != 3)
    // {
    //     fprintf(stderr, "Received %d arguments, expected 2.\n", argc - 1);
    //     fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <fd1> <fd2>", argv[0]);
    //     return 1;
    // }
    // perf_ctl_fd = atoi(argv[1]);
    // perf_ctl_ack_fd = atoi(argv[2]);

    perf_ctl_fd = atoi(getenv("PERF_CTL_FD"));
    perf_ctl_ack_fd = atoi(getenv("PERF_CTL_ACK_FD"));

    // scanf("%zu", &n);
    n = 45;

    // Start the performance counter and read the ack
    write(perf_ctl_fd, "enable\n", 8);
    read(perf_ctl_ack_fd, ack, 5);
    assert(strcmp(ack, "ack\n") == 0);

    // Compute the fibonacci number
    r = fib(n);

    // Stop the performance counter and read the ack
    write(perf_ctl_fd, "disable\n", 9);
    read(perf_ctl_ack_fd, ack, 5);
    assert(strcmp(ack, "ack\n") == 0);

    // Print the result
    printf("Result: %zu\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

```
+ mkfifo ctl_fd.fifo
+ exec {ctl_fd}<>ctl_fd.fifo
+ mkfifo ctl_fd_ack.fifo
+ exec {ctl_fd_ack}<>ctl_fd_ack.fifo
+ echo ctl_fd: $ctl_fd
ctl_fd: 10
+ echo ctrl_fd_ack: $ctl_fd_ack
ctrl_fd_ack: 11
+ PERF_CTL_FD=$ctl_fd PERF_CTL_ACK_FD=$ctl_fd_ack perf stat --delay=-1 --control fd:${ctl_fd},${ctl_fd_ack} -- build/prog
++ PERF_CTL_FD=10
++ PERF_CTL_ACK_FD=11
++ perf stat --delay=-1 --control fd:10,11 -- build/prog
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Result: 55

 Performance counter stats for 'build/prog':

          2,259.30 msec task-clock                #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
                 4      context-switches          #    1.770 /sec                   
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 /sec                   
                 0      page-faults               #    0.000 /sec                   
     7,162,104,467      cycles                    #    3.170 GHz                    
    22,618,760,242      instructions              #    3.16  insn per cycle         
     4,023,428,346      branches                  #    1.781 G/sec                  
        14,050,645      branch-misses             #    0.35% of all branches        

       2.260329786 seconds time elapsed

       0.000000000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys


+ exec {ctl_fd}>&-
+ exec {ctl_fd_ack}>&-
+ unlink ctl_fd.fifo
+ unlink ctl_fd_ack.fifo
```

Same goes with `perf record`:

```
+ mkfifo ctl_fd.fifo
+ exec {ctl_fd}<>ctl_fd.fifo
+ mkfifo ctl_fd_ack.fifo
+ exec {ctl_fd_ack}<>ctl_fd_ack.fifo
+ PERF_CTL_FD=$ctl_fd PERF_CTL_ACK_FD=$ctl_fd_ack perf record --delay=-1 --control fd:${ctl_fd},${ctl_fd_ack} -- build/prog
++ PERF_CTL_FD=10
++ PERF_CTL_ACK_FD=11
++ perf record --delay=-1 --control fd:10,11 -- build/prog
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Result: 1134903170
[ perf record: Woken up 7 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.435 MB perf.data (9053 samples) ]
+ exec {ctl_fd}>&-
+ exec {ctl_fd_ack}>&-
+ perf report
# To display the perf.data header info, please use --header/--header-only options.
#
#
# Total Lost Samples: 0
#
# Samples: 9K of event 'cycles'
# Event count (approx.): 7173277849
#
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object      Symbol                       
# ........  .......  .................  .............................
#
    99.99%  prog     prog               [.] fib
     0.01%  prog     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] rcu_check_callbacks
+ unlink ctl_fd.fifo
+ unlink ctl_fd_ack.fifo
```

Comment: Reading your C code helped a lot and I got this working. TY