# perf stat -p pid does not work with PMU events

Tags: performance, profiling, perf, energy, msr

I am trying to use `perf stat` to measure the energy consumed by part of my code. To do that, I need to run my application first and once it reaches a certain point, I run `perf stat`, passing application's pid to it using `-p` flag. While this approach works for typical performance counters, it does not work with PMU events like `power/energy-pkg/` or `power/energy-ram`. Does anyone know any workaround to capture the energy consumed by a block of the code?

**Minimal, Reproducible Example**:

```
$ cat example.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int pid= getpid();
    printf("my pid is %d\n", pid);
    sleep(15);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc example.c
$ sudo perf stat -e power/energy-pkg/ ./a.out   #(This works gracefully)
```

```
$ ./a.out &
$ pid=$!
$ sudo perf stat -e power/energy-pkg/ -p $pid      #(This doesn't work)

 Performance counter stats for process id '1749416':

   <not supported> Joules power/energy-pkg/
```

PS: I already went through the following posts, but they didn't resolve my issues:

[perf stat for part of program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267588/perf-stat-for-part-of-program)

[Perf record after my code reaches a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74340680/perf-record-after-my-code-reaches-a-certain-point)

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduce that for power events on my i7-6700k, even with a command that doesn't spend all its time asleep.  `perf stat -e power/energy-pkg/  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'`  works, `... -p $(pidof awk)` says "not supported" but works for software and CPU PMU events like `-e task-clock,cycles,instructions`.  But surprisingly, `perf stat -e power/energy-pkg/,task-clock,cycles,instructions awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'` says "not supported" for the power/energy-pkg/ event as well, so it's not just attaching, it's a problem trying to count it at the same time as PMU

Comment: Events like `power/energy-pkg/` are special, being inherently system-wide (or at least the whole package if you had a multi-socket system).

Comment: If you just want to skip startup, you can use `perf stat --delay 1000 -e ...  ./a.out` to skip the first 1000 ms of its run time.  There's also the `--control=fifo:ctl-fifo` arg that lets your program write to a pipe to send start-counting/stop-counting messages to `perf`.  The man page has an example.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just looked into `--control` option. It seems that I'd still have to pass `-p $pid` to `perf stat`, which is going to fail for RAPL counters.

Comment: If you're using `perf stat -p $pid` instead of `perf stat ./a.out` to avoid measuring part of the run-time, you can run `perf stat --control=...  ./a.out` and have the program disable counting early on before most of its startup work, then re-enable.  Like `--delay` but under the program's control.  For other use-cases of `-p $pid`, no, it doesn't help.